# Alguien sabe que es una URL arbitraria no reconocida por WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Debo hacer un plugin pero me dicen lo siguiente:

**Cuando se instala, el plugin tiene que poner a disposición un punto final personalizado en el sitio de
WordPress.
Con "punto final personalizado" nos referimos a una URL arbitraria no reconocida por WP como una
URL estándar, como un enlace permanente o así. Tenga en cuenta que no se trata de un punto de
conexión REST.**

**Cuando un visitante navega a ese punto de conexión, el complemento tiene que enviar una solicitud
HTTP a un punto de conexión de la API REST.
Cuando un visitante navega a ese punto de conexión, el complemento tiene que enviar una solicitud
HTTP a un punto de conexión de la API REST.
La API está disponible en https://jsonplaceholder. typicode.com/ y el punto de conexión al que se va
a llamar es /users.
El complemento analizará la respuesta JSON y la usará para crear y mostrar una tabla
HTML**

Debo hace esto pero no entiendo muy bien alguien que sepa a que se refiere con URl arbitraria y aclarar la pregunta general.

Gracias

Comment: Si así redactan las ayudas para sus usuarios, no me imagino como estará estructurado su software. Yo, en tu caso: **no usaría, ni aunque me paguen muy bien,** ese plugin.

Comment: Yo preguntaría en términos simples: queres una url configurable via backend donde mostrar en forma de tabla el resultado de una llamada a un api? esta tabla debe incluir header y footer del theme activo? a partir de ahí tal vez sea mas simple armarlo como un template, un shortcode o widget.

Comment: Si exactamente eso pero no se como hacerlo ya que no se como configurarla desde el backend y mostrar los datos..

Comment: la forma mas simple de "reservar"  un slug es crear una pagina, en el hook de activation testeas si está configurada y sino le haces un mini asistente al que se accede via un admin warning/message ( podes agregar un link settings al lado de activate/deactivate ) a partir de ahi le das la opción de crear una page o utilizar una ya creada, el resto del frontend lo que haría es interceptar el `template_init` de la pagina en cuestión y cambiarle el template por uno que muestre la tabla html, la cual puede estar pre armada o llenarse via ajax /1

Comment: La ventaja de usar una page y hacer override del template es que las llamadas a get header y get footer respetarían el theme instalado, ademas de poder usar varios `do_action` para disparar/definir hooks que hacen cosas extra y permitan al dev del theme personalizar un poco la salida /2

Comment: El mismo code que genera la tabla html puede exponer/proveer un shortcode por si se quiere dar la posibilidad de insertar eso en cualquier otro lado /3

Answer (score 0):

.Hay algunas direcciones que wp reserva para permalinks y cosas como categorías o tienda. Tiene que NO ser una de estas ya que esas están en uso. Puedes elegir una URL al azar y seguramente sea válida

Comment: Y como se crea una URL  de esas ?? es primera vez que escucho de ella y sabes como crearla me ayudarías mucho amigo..

Comment: Si solo quisieras crearla podrias armar una carpeta nueva en tu html public y poner algun index.html allí o agregar un archivo *.html pero por lo que veo que copiaste me da la sensación de que deberías ver la sección de configuración del plugin si no hay un lugar para configurar esta url